# Confusion in first and second order derivatives in image processing

Tags: image-processing

In image processing, the Laplacian filter adds the two second order derivatives, one in x direction and the other in y direction.

However, I am confused when we use first order derivative filters. In that case, we don't add the two first order derivatives. Instead we use the magnitude of the two first order derivatives, that is the  L2 norm of the gradient.

I want to know why we don't add these two first order derivatives like Laplacian when we use first order derivative filters. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The Laplacian is defined as the trace of the Hessian matrix. The Hessian matrix collects all second-order derivatives, which include also things like *d^2/dxdy*. The diagonal of the Hessian are the second derivative along each axis. Thus, the trace is their sum. [You should look into the determinant of the Hessian, it’s an interesting operator too.]

The gradient is a vector, composed of the partial derivative along each axis. Its magnitude (norm) is the square root of the sum of the square elements.

These things are different because they have a different meaning and a different purpose.